# how would i add a 3 and 4 photo

Tags: javascript, onclick, attributes

how would i add 3,4 more photos because i cant seem to get it working i am a new at javascrpt

```html
<html>

<body>

  <button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='1.jpg'">Turn on the light</button>

  <img id="myImage" src="2.jpg" style="width:100px">


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: What do you mean "add 3,4 more photos". Your current code seems to be working, and it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: so when i click button it goes to next photo

Comment: Please, [attempt to solve the issue on your own](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) before asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <button onclick="function() {
            // get current image name.
            var imgName = document.getElementById('myImage').src;
            // get index of current image.
            var imageIndex = imgName.replace('.jpg', '');
            // if current image is a last index, make it 1,
            // otherwise increment the index
            imageIndex = imageIndex === 4 ? 1 : imageIndex + 1;

            // set the next image
            document.getElementById('myImage').src=`${imageIndex}.jpg`
        }">Turn on the light</button>
        <img id="myImage" src="1.jpg" style="width:100px">
    </body>
</html>
```